# responseXML returns null

Tags: xmlhttprequest, isnull

Good morning!

I've been trying to parse a KML document as it is a XML document doing an http request but the response of it is null. I've read that maybe is because it doesn't have propper headings but I have to use a server of which I don't have any control, I can only upload files. The encoding is especified too so I don't know where is the problem. Here is the code:

```
url="http://www4.uji.es/~al106651/tracks/"+folder+"/El_Destierro_02_(Burgos-Modubar)"+ext
document.getElementById("url").innerHTML=url;

kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(url, {map:map} );

//Analize KML
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
url="/tracks/1.el_destierro/El_Destierro_02_(Burgos-Modubar).KML";
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; //here's the trouble..

document.getElementById("xml").innerHTML = 
xmlDoc.getElementById("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

What should it be? Thanks very much.

Comment: Apparently the problem was that my files where .KML and the server doesn't specify any headers so responseXML was null. I had to use a script to change all file names from .KML to .xml and it worked.

Comment: Hi David, if that solved your question, you can put it as a proper answer and mark it as answered. This way, next time someone has a similar problem, you'll have provided them the answer :)